# Filter the data in one query based on the result from another query in Cognos

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi, cognos-8, cognos-11

I need to use a column data obtained in a query in Q1 as a filter in Q2. Is there a way? Can anyone please suggest? I'm a beginner.

PS: Need to pull the report based on the country.
I have 3 columns in Q1 ---> User Name, User ID, User email
3 columns in Q2--> User ID, user location and user country
A join condition between Q1.userID and Q2.userID works.
but I need to create a report that pulls the users details based on the country I select.

Comment: Your question and description don't match.  It looks like you want to use Q2 to filter Q1.  Is that correct?

Comment: Please show your data structure to include what columns are returned by each query.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to do this via a proper model instead of modelling in the report.  That being said, in a pinch,  you could set the allow cross join query hint on both queries and create a filter similar to:

```
[Query1].[UserID]=[Query2].[UserID] and [Query2].[Country]=?p_Country?
```